# What is the purpose of condenser lenses in the slide projector shown below?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I searched a lot on internet about this.I could not find the working of these condenser lenses in detail. Some websites say that condenser lenses make the light rays parallel and  to pass through every part of the slide. I can not figure out how?
Moreover those websites say nothing about  replacing these condenser lenses with a single convex lens.I also wonder what will happen if we place the condenser lenses with their plane faces facing each other?
I need help[image]

Comment: You have duplicated your question, I think you should remove the other one. Nice figure. The the condenser lens is used to increase the intensity at the object.